# How to find count and percentage of that count again over all in teradata

Tags: teradata

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbSa6.png)

```
Name   Date          Key       sce
Apple 1/1/2022    1111        1
Apple 1/1/2022    123        -11
Apple 1/1/2022    3435       -11
Mango 1/1/2022   14124       1
Mango 1/1/2022   1314       -11
Mango 1/2/2022   424          1
Mango 1/2/2022    5136      -11
Mango 1/2/2022   156          1
Mango 1/2/2022   1111      -11
```

i'm looking for an output like below i.e. for each name  and for each date, count of all -11's and percentage of -11 over the total

ex: for 1/1/2022, apple has two -11 in column sce so the count should be 2 and percentage should to (2/3) *100.. Can you please help

```
Name    date                        count (of -11's)        percentage ( of all -11's over total)
Apple   1/1/2022                     2                                    66.7
Mango   1/1/2022                     1                                    50.0
Mango   1/2/2022                     2                                    50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case expression to limit what rows are counted by a condition:

```
SELECT name,
    date,
    count(CASE WHEN sce = -11 THEN sce END) as "count",
    100.0 * count(CASE WHEN sce = -11 THEN sce END)/count(*) as "percentage"
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name, date
```

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth I updated with that so they get a percentage back with a single digit after the decimal.